# How do find XPath when only value is given in the source code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

What will be the XPath of a 'Search' button from the expression mentioned above?

Comment: Your question has only one statement. What do you mean by "expression mentioned above".

Comment: Please edit your question to add the source code, what you have tried, and the results you received.

Comment: Please add code snippet of an XPath and an HTML page of your DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to come up with the correct XPath locator without seeing the source code of the page you're trying to automate.

Here are few hints:

1. If the element is a [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)  which looks like:

   ```
   <button class="favorite styled"
           type="button">
       Search
   </button>
   ```

   the relevant XPath locator would be

   ```
   //button[text()='Search']
   ```
2. If the element is an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button) with the [value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) attribute which looks like:

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Search">
   ```

   the relevant XPath locator would be:

   ```
   //input[@value='Search']
   ```
3. It's also possible to use [XPath Functions or Operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for example for partial match:

   ```
   //input[contains(@value, 'Search')]
   ```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)

Answer (score 1):

### Using the browser dev tools

In Chrome, I believe that you can get the Xpath value for *any* element by:

1. Opening the Developer Tools for your page
2. Clicking on the Elements tab.
3. Right-clicking on the target element and choosing Copy -> Copy Xpath.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Using the placeholder text (when available)

Although all the answers given above are correct and would help you. But i just want to add my thoughts/work or suggestions for handling such type of elements like 'Search', login and Signup fields and buttons. 
For Search field case:

1. For every search field it will be an input field so you are sure about input tag.
2. Than how you got to know that it is a search field - By looking into the text inside that field(we call it placeholder text) and interpreting it. Placeholder must have the text like "Search" , "find" etc.
   So combining and observing the above two points you can come up with css/xpath locator, which could be like:

   xpath = //input[@placeholder="Search for products"]

   css   = input[placeholder="Search for products"]

   Other alternatives:

   xpath = //input[@any-attribute-having-text="Search"]

   xpath = //input[contains(@any-attribute-contains-text,"Search")]

Hope it helps in your software testing services for building locators of other fields also, like username, password, firstname, lastname.